# call funtion javascript from c# with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#

I call a Javascript function from C# using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`,  up to this point all is good, this call my function without problems.

The problem occurs when I call the same function with distincts parameters, debugging the js function in Chrome or Firefox I saw that the parameters received are different to the ones sent in C#.

The question is: why are my parameters different js side and C# side? It is the cache?

Thanks for your time cheers!!!

My code C# side:

```
var JsonSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = JsonSerial.Serialize(lst);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Mensaje", "PaintList('" + json + "','1');", true);
```

In js side:

```
function PaintList(arr, num) {
```

Here is where I see diferent parameters

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: What is different? What do you expect as a parameter and what do you actually get? Show us the values

Comment: what is in json here `json = JsonSerial.Serialize(lst);`

Comment: Make the first line of PaintList `console.log(arr, num)` and add the output of that to your question please.